# Load a dropdown from a second dropdown Ajax to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am loading a list of customers and I want to load a second dropdown for locations based on which customer gets selected. For some reason my code isn't working. Here's my code:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">
    <select name="sCustomer" id="sCustomer" onChange="findLocations(this.value)">
        <option value="0">- Select Customer -</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span style="display:inline-block;">
    <select id="sLocation" name="sLocation">
        <option value="0">- Select Location -</option>
    </select>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

function findLocations(custID) {
    $('#sLocation').empty();
    $('#sLocation').append("<option value='0'>- Select Location -</option>");
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"getLocations.php",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { custID : custID },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){ 
        $.each(data,function(i, item){
            $('#iTest').val("bobby");
            $('#sLocation').empty();
            $('#sLocation').append("<option value='0'>- Select Location -</option>");
            $('#sLocation').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
        });
    },
    complete: function(){

    }
});
}

</script>
```

and the page it calls has this code

```
<?php 
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.error.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.role.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.passwd.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.user.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.auth.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.location.php');

function getLocations() {  
    $custID = 0; 

    if (isset($_POST['custID'])) {
        $custID = $_POST['custID'];
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT l.location_id, l.site_name FROM ' . CUST_LOCATION_TABLE
        . ' AS l JOIN ' . CUST_TABLE . ' AS c ON c.cust_id=l.cust_id'
            . ' WHERE c.cust_id='.$custID;

    $locations = array();

    if (($res=db_query($sql)) && db_num_rows($res)) {
        while(list($id,$name)=db_fetch_row($res)) { 
            $columns = array (
                    'locID' => $id,
                    'locName' => $name,
            );
            $locations[] = $columns;
        }
    }
  return $locations;
}

?>
```

Why isn't this working and is there anyway to test what part is breaking? I can't echo out anything because the page doesn't postback (since it's ajax) and I can't do javascript alert in the ajax function. Bear in mind I didn't add the code that was filling the customer dropdown because I know it's working right, populating everything and giving me the correct values.

Okay I found this which at least helps me start debugging. It's failing but I found this

```
error: function (request, error) {
    console.log(arguments);
    alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
},
```

Comment: echo the response and check in you console.log() at javascript

Comment: Dont you need to call `echo json_encode(getLocations());` for the json to be sent

Comment: Where would I call that echo statement? I am new to php and the last time I programmed with ajax it wasn't as fancy. I had to write out all the Http requests so I'm trying to learn the new way.

Comment: you have included your whole php code in function,  where is function call ?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
data: { custID : custID },
```

with

```
data: { 'custID' : custID },
```

in javascript

Comment: use it `data: "custID="+custID ,`

Comment: are you getting value at server side

Comment: Dude you have not calling `getLocations()` inside your php file only defination is there

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code in php file with this one

```
if (($res=db_query($sql)) && db_num_rows($res)) {
        $str = "";
        $str .= "<option value='0'>Select Location</option>";

        while(list($id,$name)=db_fetch_row($res)) { 

              $str .= "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
        }
    }
echo $str;
```

Now Modify your javascript function

```
function findLocations(custID) {
$('#sLocation').empty();

$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"getLocations.php",
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: { custID : custID },
dataType:"json",
success: function(data){ 
   document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = data; 
},
complete: function(){

}
});
}
```

Comment: Where and how do I set the response in the javascript function? I haven't coded in about 5 years so I'm extremely rusty with coding. Would I set it in the ajax request on success or just right inside the findLocations function?

Comment: @ManateeInfuser : answer updated replace ur javascript function with this one

Comment: you need to update ur PHP code too, remove getLocations() around the code

Comment: Now I am actually getting to the code thank you! Though I still don't get any results. The dropdown is blank after running this code. Is there a way to debug the php page? I have eclipse but I've never been able to get the debugger to stop at breakpoints.

Comment: have you removed that php function ?

Comment: Actually it still doesn't look like I'm reaching the code. I changed it to this and I still get an empty dropdown box.

Comment: Yeah here is my current code with all comments removed.

Comment: remove function getLocations() {  } keep inside code as it is

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLocations(custID) {
$('#sLocation').empty();

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"getLocations.php",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { custID : custID },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){ 
       document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = "<option value='0'>- Select Locationss -</option>"; // + data;
        },
        complete: function(){

        }
    });
}
```

and the php page is

```
 <?php 
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.error.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.role.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.passwd.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.user.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.auth.php');
include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.location.php');


$custID = 0; 

if (isset($_POST['custID'])) {
    $custID = $_POST['custID'];
}

$sql = 'SELECT l.location_id, l.site_name FROM ' . CUST_LOCATION_TABLE
    . ' AS l JOIN ' . CUST_TABLE . ' AS c ON c.cust_id=l.cust_id'
    . ' WHERE c.cust_id='.$custID;

$locations = array();

if (($res=db_query($sql)) && db_num_rows($res)) {
    $str = "";
    $str .= "<option value='0'>Select Location</option>";

    while(list($id,$name)=db_fetch_row($res)) { 
          $str .= "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
    }
}
echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: it should be like document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = data

Comment: I did that and I was getting an empty dropdown so I set the innerHTML to at least have the Select Location option and it still didn't add it which means, at least if I'm right, that it's not getting to the success.

Comment: above document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = data line add "alert(data);" without quote it will show you response

Comment: Didn't alert anything, so I don't think it's getting to the success of the ajax call. Is there an on error that I could try alerting the error?

Comment: it must alert, check console there must be some error, also remove <option value="0">- Select Location -</option> from ur html just keep it
<select id="sLocation" name="sLocation">
       
    </select>

Comment: I never knew about the console and it has the wrong url! I'm modifying an open source ticketing system and they are extremely convoluted in their coding. Gonna change the url and see if that works, which I'm assuming it will work after that.